# Что означает сохранение состояния компьютерных программ?

Tags: ассемблер

В ассемблере встретил понятие PSP.

Program Segment Prefix — структура данных, которая используется в операционных системах семейства DOS и CP/M для **сохранения состояния** компьютерных программ.

Что означает "**сохранения состояния**" в данном случае?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, не совсем удачный перевод. Как таковое, состояние программы - под которым обычно понимается содержимое регистров, стека и памяти - там не хранится. Используется PSP в первую очередь для получения аргументов командной строки и переменных среды. Для разных хакерских трюков может использоваться и другая информация (типа PSP родителя), но, насколько я припоминаю, в "обычных" программах используются только указанная информация.

Comment: Функции 4e/4f int 21h (поиск файла) для хранения состояния поиска (на чем остановились) ипользуют область DTA, по умолчанию расположенную в PSP

Comment: @Mike Это внутреннее использование PSP системой, а я пытался ответить на вопрос PSP для программиста.